# How to download latest builds from the Monero Buildbot?

Tags: build

Monero has a BuildBot that automatically compiles the latest Monero builds for multiple operating systems [here](https://build.getmonero.org/). I cannot find an option to actually download these builds. For instance, suppose I want to download the latest build of Kovri for Windows x64. How can I do this?

Comment: click on builders. choose the os you have. click a successful build and there is a link near the bottom. for example https://build.getmonero.org/builders/monero-core-win64/builds/642 has https://build.getmonero.org/downloads/monero-core-57ae6df-win64.zip

Comment: @samwellj should it show up under the "steps and logfiles" section?

Comment: ya just below that under 'upload' there is a zip file with binaries

Answer (score 4):

You can download the files for the build you would like to examine under the "Steps and Logfiles" section. For Windows, you will often find a .zip file. The file you can download is underlined in red.

[image]

Not all builds will have files you can download and run.

Finally, since these are not official releases, they may not be stable or as safe as official releases. Use these only for testing purposes with care, not for storing any Monero.

Comment: maybe just mention that these binaries may not be stable because they are not official releases?

Comment: @samwellj updated